# I got some problems with scanf function in C. When i compile it It shows message of : Segmentation error

Tags: c

Okay let me be specific here. I want to build a program with **scanf** function, that will ask user to enter information like this sample:

1. Enter your age here_                          (suppose i type 16 in my age)
   (*1st output*) : Your age is 16
2. Enter your name here_                         (suppose i type john )
   (*2nd output*) : Your name is john 
   Now without asking anything from the user, it should automatically give output like : 
   (*3rd output*) : Your name is John and your age is 16.

There is an image below that will show my error :
[Image captured by me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCvwQ.png)

My first and second output run well but problem is with the 3rd one. It doesn't show the whole 3rd output in compiler. but instead of showing errors or warnings it shows a text saying "Segmentation fault". Please correct my code. Please please please.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int age;
char name;

printf("Enter your age here: ");
scanf("%d", &age);
printf("Your age is %d \n", age);

printf("enter your name here: \n");
scanf("%s", &name);

printf("Your name is %s and your age is %d.", name, age);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need an allocated char[] to store `name`. Change `char name`, by `char name[20]` and pass name to  scanf().

Comment: Oh My God. Hats off Alain for quick response and right answer. Really really Thanks a lot. : )

Comment: @AndrewWhiteman warning, protect the _scanf_ to not write out of the string, if you have size 20 do `if (scanf("%19s", name) != 1) ...error...` (1 less to have the place for the ending null character, and check not EOF). I also encourage you to check `if (scanf("%d", &age) != 1) ...error...` to verify a valid int was given by the user

Comment: Thanks @bruno... I will keep this in mind. Well my code has now compiled successfully. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared a char but you're treating it like a string. In C, strings are actually one-dimensional arrays of chars, with a null character '\0' at the end.

The following:

```
"my fun string"
```

equates to this in C:

```
{'m', 'y', ' ', 'f', 'u', 'n', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'}
```

You need to allocate a char array large enough for the name. Something like the following:

`int max_size=120; char name[max_size];`

so your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age;

    int max_size=120;
    char name[max_size];
    printf("Enter your age here: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Your age is %d.\n", age);

    printf("enter your name here: \n");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    printf("Your name is %s and your age is %d.\n", name, age);

    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, you probably shouldn't use `scanf()`. `fgets()` is preferable.

Comment: Using VLAs here is redundant.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &name);` is a bad a `gets()`.  Better to use `scanf("%119s", name);` here.

Comment: Wow! thanks dude. It helped me a lot. My compile ran successfully. thanks @junior_software  :)